# Why isn't setjmp in the std namespace when including <csetjmp>?

Tags: c++, std, setjmp

The title say it all. After including `<csetjmp>`, `longjmp` and `jmp_buf` are in the `std` namespace, but `setjmp`is not. I verified this on MinGW4.5 and MSVC10. After looking into the `<csetjmp>` header, I could not figure out the reason of this choice. I was always assuming that every `<cheader>` file is wrapping a `<header.h>` in the `std` namespace.

Am I wrong ? What's the rationale behind the `setjmp` special case ? Please enlighten me !

<sub>Note : I'm aware of the issues of misusing setjmp/longjmp in C++.</sub>

Comment: Is `sigsetjmp()` available as a preferred replacement?

Comment: No, I've no sigsetjmp available neither inside and outside the std namespace after including <csetjmp>.

Comment: To disable it, hopefully.  But no, macros don't have namespace scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setjmp` can be implemented as a macro, so the C++ standard has this to say in 17.6.1.2 [headers]:

> Names which are defined as macros in C shall be defined as macros in
>   the C++ standard library, even if C grants license for implementation
>   as functions. [ Note: The names defined as macros in C include the
>   following: `assert`, `offsetof`, `setjmp`, `va_arg`, `va_end`, and
>   `va_start`. —end note ]

In other words, it's a macro.

Comment: Thanks ! But isn't it possible to define an alias like this : `# define std::setjmp  setjmp` ?

Comment: @overcoder: It's not possible because a macro name can only be a single identifier.